# Menu android in material desing

Tags: android

How create menu 
https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-usage

The is PopupMenu or Spinnet?

Answer (score 1):

The menu shown with the contacts is simply an Options menu as defined in the [SDK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

Android will automatically position and manage your menu provided that you populate it in the activity.

> If you've developed your application for **Android 3.0 (API level 11) and higher**, items from the options menu are available in the app bar. By default, the system places all items in the action overflow, which the user can reveal with the action overflow icon on the right side of the app bar (or by pressing the device Menu button, if available).
>
> To enable quick access to important actions, you can promote a few items to appear in the app bar by adding `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to the corresponding `<item>` elements (see figure 2).

To add to a menu, see [Activity.onCreateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu))

Comment: Give [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) page a read. It's the full documentation for these menus

Comment: Paul Thompson The is  PopupWindow?http://s018.radikal.ru/i520/1511/e1/5f1bbf083695.png